Where to put .debug file in AppDir?
I want to create AppImage of my application with debug symbols, because it crashes.
Where should I put .debug file containing that info in AppDir? AppDir/usr/lib/debug/? Are there any conventions?
My system is Kubuntu 24.04, I will use the last stable version of appimagetool to make AppImage. The question pertain both release and debug builds, preferably release build though.
